# Getting JavaScript input and displaying on the screen without a prompt

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, document

I am learning JavaScript and I came across a problem that I do not yet know how to fix. I'm making a simple average calculator, that takes 2 inputs from the user ( i am not using prompts ), here is what I used:

```
<form>
    <input type="number" name="number1" id="first_num"/>
</form>
```

This is for the first number. What I fail to achieve is displaying the text in the console. Here is how I tried to do it:

```
var answer_1 = document.getElementById('first_num').value;
console.log(answer_1);
```

--- not necessarily to the screen, but to the console. When I change the number is should display the number that is currently showing up. What I get instead is an error saying: `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`, yet there is a number in the box.

My goal is to display the number that is written in by the user to the screen. Can I do that without using a button?

Comment: check if  document.getElementById('first_num') is null

Comment: Your code may be running before you declared this element. Try putting your script at the bottom of <body>

Comment: the JaveScript code is imported from another document

Comment: I did it with a button and it works, but how do I change the `text` inside a `div` so that the answer is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, the problem was that I used a `submit` button, and whenever the button was clicked it refreshed the page. So the text was displayed on the screen, but the screen was immediately refreshed so it was gone again. Thank you guys!